# converting .xls format to xlsx that connect inside the azure storage using python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Hello I had a question

I have seen many codes regarding converting .xls to .xlsx format but in local do you have any ideas on how to call the azure container to convert the xls to xlsx format using python notebook?

to get a code in converting the excel file into xlsx by calling azure storage

Comment: Have you tried any code, if yes can you provide it in the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Converting the Excel file into xlsx by calling Azure storage

You can use the below code to convert the **`xls`** file into **`xlsx`** in Azure storage using Azure Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import xlrd
import openpyxl
import io

connection_string = "your-connection-string"
container_name = "test1"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blob_name = "samplexlsfile.xls"
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
excel_bytes = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
excel_file = io.BytesIO(excel_bytes)
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=excel_file.read())
xlsx_workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()

for sheet_name in workbook.sheet_names():
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    xlsx_worksheet = xlsx_workbook.create_sheet(sheet_name)
    for row_idx in range(worksheet.nrows):
        row_data = worksheet.row_values(row_idx)
        for col_idx, cell_value in enumerate(row_data):
            xlsx_worksheet.cell(row=row_idx+1, column=col_idx+1, value=cell_value)
xlsx_bytes = io.BytesIO()
xlsx_workbook.save(xlsx_bytes)
xlsx_bytes.seek(0)

new_blob_name = "demo456.xlsx"
new_blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(new_blob_name)
new_blob_client.upload_blob(xlsx_bytes, overwrite=True)
blob_client.delete_blob()
```

The above code is used to convert the xls into xlsx file and delete the original xls file.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thank you but I do not know why your code is not working on .ipbynb  huhu

Comment: this code was from here also but the problem is when I run the file sas url do not read the blob url

**bold** `from xls2xlsx import XLS2XLSX
import os
import pandas as pd

 if filename.endswith(".xls"):
       df = pd.read_excel(filename)
       df.to_excel(filename + ".xlsx")`


is there some limitation in coding in python notebook ?